# Do we still have CU for SharePoint 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2016, cumulative-update

Last week I planned to upgrade our SharePoint 2016 Farm to latest CUs available but when searched on internet I didn't find it. I can only find security update and Feature Pack. Do we have CU for SharePoint 2016?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**As a short answer:** **Yes,**

We still have Cumulative Updates for SharePoint 2016 and you can install the latest **Feb 2018 CU** from [February 2018 CU for SharePoint Server 2016 is available for download](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2018/02/13/february-2018-cu-for-sharepoint-server-2016-is-available-for-download/)

> **Note:** A feature pack is a group of new product features and functionality updates that were requested by customers. The Feature
>   Pack is a subset of the Cumulative Update. where the `Feature Pack 2`
>   is **included** in the Sept 2017 Cumulative Update for SharePoint
>   2016.

---

Check also

- Stefan Goßner blog to find all Published CU/SP/FP/PU for All SharePoint versions : [February 2018 CU for SharePoint Server 2016 is available for download](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2018/02/13/february-2018-cu-for-sharepoint-server-2016-is-available-for-download/)
- [Find farm patch level / latest cumulative update that has been installed on sharepoint farm](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/11/30/find-latest-cumulative-update-installed-in-sharepoint-farm/)

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I still have confusion related to this as when you click the KB4011680 link provided in your comment, it opens a page where it says that "This public update delivers the first feature pack (Feature Pack 1) for SharePoint Server 2016 " [Description of the security update for SharePoint Enterprise Server 2016: February 13, 2018](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4011680/descriptionofthesecurityupdateforsharepointentserver2016february13-201") <br/>

Comment: So till now I have not seen any single support page of Microsoft stating about CU for SharePoint 2016.

Comment: Stefan Goßner is an Escalation Engineer at Microsoft and all articles is official and in the same article, he mentioned you can install the Feb CU from here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56581